# Erro ao executar mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Quando eu executo o `mysql_query` ele da o seguinte erro(mesmo eu conseguindo fazer a conexão com o banco de dados sem maiores problemas)

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor\index.php on line 57

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor\index.php on line 57
```

O código inteiro

```
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "senha", "bd") or die('ERRO AO LOGAR!');
        if (!$connect) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $name = 'Barbie e sua amiga no paraiso';
        $categoria = 'Serie';
        $download = 1569;
        $upload = 1694;
        $magnet = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:B250C87526B32E9421AA8FB7599FC11CF3FD1275&dn=Morgan%20-%20A%20Evolu%c3%a7%c3%a3o%202016%20Bluray%20720p%20Dublado%20-%20TPF&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.opentrackr.org%3a1337%2fannounce';

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO torrents(`Nome`, `Categoria`, `DownloadQuantity`, `UploadQuantity`, `Magnet`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$categoria."', '".$download."', '".$upload."', '".$magnet."')");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer desta forma nessa ordem de conexão: `DB_HOST`, `DB_NOME_USUARIO`, `DB_SENHA`, `DB_NOME_BANCO`. Veja:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "senha", "bd");

// verifica se encontrou algum erro na conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();            
}
```

Veja também que o `$download` e `$upload` estão como inteiros, porém na *query* você está usando `'".$upload."'` e `'".$download."'`, como *strings*.

```
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO torrents(`Nome`, `Categoria`, `DownloadQuantity`, `UploadQuantity`, `Magnet`) 
VALUES ('".$name."', '".$categoria."', '".$download."', '".$upload."', '".$magnet."')");
```

Faça desta forma:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO torrents(`Nome`, `Categoria`, `DownloadQuantity`, `UploadQuantity`, `Magnet`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$categoria."', ".$download.", ".$upload.", '".$magnet."')");
```

Além também de estar não está encontrando uma conexão de acordo com o usuário.

Comment: Fiz dessa forma e o erro continua.

Comment: Testei a conexão, e o erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: @LucasCarezia o nome de usuário e senha é esse mesmo?

Comment: Com certeza, já que consigo conectar com o `mysqli_connect` sem retornar erros.

Comment: Retorna `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor\index.php on line 56`

Answer (score 4):

Você está usando `mysqli_connect` e utilizando `mysql_query` sem o `i`, ele não encontra a conexão e diz acesso negado ao usuário `''` pq ele não encontra a conexão.